# How create many count meshes quickly

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I generate meshes (about 40 000) in edit mode, and I need create prefabs from gameobjects (that contains this meshes). So I need save meshes. I try with some code:

```
UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(meshRenderer.sharedMaterial, pathMaterial);
```

But its very long (because many count meshes), How optimize this process?

Comment: I find solution: save as obj, buy its create new copy mesh and material for each material and mesh

Comment: I use http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=ObjExporter, but it create new copy mesh and materials for each object.